# Error handling with Lambda function applied to a DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

Doing the following :

```
self.FUTcurve['Maturity'] = self.FUTcurve.apply(
            lambda x: blp.bdp(x.security_description,"X")["X"][0], axis=1)
```

does not work since sometimes

```
blp.bdp(x.security_description,"X")
```

returns an empty array.

I know how to handle error but nut in lamnda func ..
The error raised is :

KeyError: 'X'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
self.FUTcurve['Maturity'] = self.FUTcurve.apply(
            lambda x: 'empty array' if 'X' not in blp.bdp(x.security_description,"X") else blp.bdp(x.security_description,"X")["X"][0], axis=1)
```

Cleaner solution:

```
def my_func(x):
    arr = blp.bdp(x.security_description, "X")
    if 'X' in arr:
        return arr['X'][0]
    else:
        return 'empty array'   
self.FUTcurve['Maturity'] = self.FUTcurve.apply(lambda x: my_func(x))
```

Directly calling the `security_description` column:

```
def my_func(x):
    arr = blp.bdp(x, "X")
    if 'X' in arr:
        return arr['X'][0]
    else:
        return 'empty array'   
self.FUTcurve['Maturity'] = self.FUTcurve['security_description'].apply(my_func)
```

Comment: Can we add x.security_description as argument of my_func ?

Comment: So I can change column calling function

Comment: I have modified the solution, can you check